# What use instead of global variables in scipy weave?

Tags: python, c, scipy

I'm doing simulation of dynamics of some particle in forcefield described by a **lot of parameters**.

If I do this in C or Fortran I would define these parametes as global variables (it si most convenient). Here when I'm using scipy weave I have to pass them as arguments of functions. Which I don't like because **I have to edit header of many functions every time I add or remove a parameter**. Also the calling of the function can slow down because of passing many arguments (it is performance critical tight loop).

for example in the following code the parameters `k, x_surf, C6, C12, CQ, zeta, e0` and `T1, beta` **are passed in header of several dependent functions again and again**.

```
inline double getForce( 
    double x, double Q,   
    double k, double x_surf, double C6, double C12, double CQ, double zeta, double e0
){ ... }

inline void move( 
    double dt, double imass, double T1, double beta,   
    double k,  double x_surf, double C6, double C12, double CQ, double zeta, double e0,        
    double &x, double &v, double &Q 
){
   ...
   double f = getForce( x, Q,     k, x_surf, C6, C12, CQ, zeta, e0 );
   ...
}

void trj2buff( 
    double dt, int nsteps, double mass, double T1, double beta,    
    double k, double x_surf, double C6, double C12, double CQ, double zeta, double e0,         
    double  x_start, double  v_start, double  Q_start,
    double* x_buff,  double* v_buff,  double* Q_buff 
){
   ...
   move( dt, imass,  T1, beta,     k, Q, x_surf, C6, C12, CQ, zeta, e0,        x, v, Q );
   ...
}
```

One solution would be probably to pass all the parameters as a single `double*` buffer (but it would make the code less readable because it would nod be named). Or better as an user defined `struct{}`. But it is not clear to me, how to use `struct{}` with scipy weave in this case.

Comment: It's usually around this point of complexity that you should start writing an extension module instead of using `scipy.weave`.

Comment: Do you know about a good tutorial how to do an extension module like that? I was reading a few articles about `distutils` but it is a broad topic. I would like something more specific about numerical simulations and going from weave to extension modules.

Comment: I recommend using [Cython](http://www.cython.org/) to help you generate your extension module. It has [good support for numpy arrays](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html).